# MySQL throwing error on create table. No idea why

Tags: php, mysql

```
$invited = "CREATE TABLE invited (id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id), name VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255), permissions VARCHAR(255))";
mysqli_query($dbc, $invited) or die ('Error creating invited');
```

What is wrong with this code? Keeps giving me "Error creating invited"

Comment: Instead of just `die()` output the error message using `mysqli_error( $dbc )`!

Comment: you dont specified type of id column (e.g. int)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `ID` data type

```
CREATE TABLE invited 
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ...
        ^--------------------------------------here
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
CREATE TABLE `invited` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: You can even have it in this multi-line format so it is easy to read by using a [heredoc](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or a [nowdoc](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).